# Share USB NIC over VMware

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, virtualization, vmware

I have a host system running Ubuntu 18.04 and VMware 14.x and a guest OS of Windows 7

The only active interface on the system is a Verizon USB Dongle (4G)

The dongle works fine for the Ubuntu host, but when I attempt to launch the Windows 7 VM I receive the following error:

```
The specified device is claimed by another driver (cdc_ether) on the host 

operating system. The device might be in use. To continue, the device will 

first be disconnected from its current driver.
```

If I go ahead an launch the VM, both operating systems will have NO connectivity.

From what I can tell, the Linux host is locking the USB and when VMware tries to access it the USB becomes disconnected and I lose all connectivity.

I have playing with networking settings in VMware (Bridged, NAT, etc) None of these settings seemed to help.

Does anyone here have any experience/solution for this?

Comment: Any device disconnected from the host will work in the guest provided that OS supports it. You would need to install drivers, if required, the same way you would do in an installed system. So, when you disconnect it from the host and pass it to the guest, if the guest (Ubuntu) has no drivers for said device nothing will work obviously. But you don't need to do that and there are only a few situations in that it would make sense to pass a network device to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The error I was getting occurs because VMware is actually grabbing possession of the USB port. Only one system can 'own' the usb port.

Normally, in a networking context, this wouldn't matter. VMware is designed to working with the host's network interfaces. It doesn't try and take full possession of the network interfaces, it just routes traffic through them.

However, in my situation the eth0 and wlan0 were both disconnected from the internet, so when the guest OS took possession of the usb port I lost connectivity. As @GabrielaGarcia mentions in the comment, the guest doesn't have the drivers to deal with the USB card.

**Solution**

I went to the USB NIC's webUI and grabbed the routing information. I then created a [Virtual Network](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018697?ui-force-components-controllers-hostConfig.HostConfig.getConfigData=1&r=3&other.KM_Utility.getArticleDetails=1&other.KM_Utility.getArticleMetadata=1&other.KM_Utility.getAllTranslatedLanguages=1&ui-comm-runtime-components-aura-components-siteforce-qb.Quarterback.validateRoute=1) in VMware and pointed the Guest traffic at the same Gateway which the USB NIC was pointed to. (Use NAT mode in the virtual network editor)

After that it just started working.

Note: If it is not working check in VMware settings for "removable devices". From that option menu you can ensure that the guest has released the USB device (or other device).